# What is the best way to map each row in a DF to a row from another DF after comparing the first row with multiple rows from the second DF?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, One contains different dates and different player_id. The second one contains the history of each player's rating, which means it contains different dates and different player_id and player_rating with a unique id of each row.

Now, I want to add a column to the first DataFrame with the one value of the player_rating by comparing the date columns in the two DataFrames.

For example:

```
print(df_1)

   date  player_id
0  2006          1
1  2006          2
2  2012          3
3  2008          2
4  2010          1

print(df_2)

   date  player_id  player_rating
0  2005          1             50
1  2007          2             55
2  2005          3             70
3  2005          2             65
4  2009          1             60
5  2011          2             75
6  2011          3             85
```

Here, I should compare the first row in df_1 with the first and fifth rows in df_2 (the same player_id) then choose the row from df_2 with the most updated date and smaller than the date in df_1. So, I should choose the first row and set the player_rating to 50.

Finally, I should get:

```
print(df_1)
   date  player_id  player_rating
0  2006          1             50
1  2006          2             65
2  2012          3             85
3  2008          2             55
4  2010          1             60
```

I have tried many solutions and get the following idea but it takes much time to run relative to a huge dataset (about one million rows of df_1 and +100k rows of df_2):

```
def get_rating(date, player_id):
    return df_2[(df_2['player_id']==player_id) & (df_2['date'] < date)].sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=False).player_rating.iloc[0]
df_1['player_rating'] = [get_rating(x,y) for x, y in zip(df_1['date'], df_1['player_id'])]
```

If there is a better way to save some time here?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to test for efficiency though:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='player_id', how = 'left', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
    .sort_values(['date', 'date_y'])
    .query('date > date_y')
    .groupby(['date', 'player_id'])
    .tail(1)
    .drop(columns='date_y')
    .sort_index()
  )
 
     date  player_id  player_rating
0   2006          1             50
3   2006          2             65
6   2012          3             85
7   2008          2             55
11  2010          1             60
```

Comment: Very nice solution. For a bigger dataframe maybe sorting after querying could be faster.

Comment: Using merge and tail were very simple solutions. And as rapani said, using sort after querying was fast. For +25k rows of df_1, it took 2 seconds using the first solution, and it took 1.8 seconds by sorting after querying. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can try to merge the two dataframe on `player_id` and then use your logic regarding dates.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': {0: 2006, 1: 2006, 2: 2012, 3: 2008, 4: 2010},
     'player_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}})

df2 =  pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': {0: 2005, 1: 2007, 2: 2005, 3: 2005, 4: 2009, 5: 2011, 6: 2011},
     'player_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3},
     'player_rating': {0: 50, 1: 55, 2: 70, 3: 65, 4: 60, 5: 75, 6: 85}})
```

## Merge

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["player_id"])
```

Where the data looks like

```sh
    date_x  player_id  date_y  player_rating
0     2006          1    2005             50
1     2006          1    2009             60
2     2010          1    2005             50
3     2010          1    2009             60
4     2006          2    2007             55
5     2006          2    2005             65
6     2006          2    2011             75
7     2008          2    2007             55
8     2008          2    2005             65
9     2008          2    2011             75
10    2012          3    2005             70
11    2012          3    2011             85
```

## Filter

Now you ask for `date_x` bigger than `date_y`

```py
df = df[df["date_x"].gt(df["date_y"])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And you have

```sh
   date_x  player_id  date_y  player_rating
0    2006          1    2005             50
1    2010          1    2005             50
2    2010          1    2009             60
3    2006          2    2005             65
4    2008          2    2007             55
5    2008          2    2005             65
6    2012          3    2005             70
7    2012          3    2011             85
```

## Use groupby to find the latest date for each year

Here we look for the index where date_y is bigger within the group.

```py
grp = df.groupby(["date_x", "player_id"])["date_y"].idxmax()
print(grp)
```

```sh
date_x  player_id
2006    1            0
        2            3
2008    2            4
2010    1            2
2012    3            7
Name: date_y, dtype: int64
```

So we filter with these indices

```py
df = df[df.index.isin(grp.values)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which looks like

```sh
   date_x  player_id  date_y  player_rating
0    2006          1    2005             50
1    2010          1    2009             60
2    2006          2    2005             65
3    2008          2    2007             55
4    2012          3    2011             85
```

and we drop columns and rename the first one.

```py
df = df.drop(columns=["date_y"])\
    .rename(columns={"date_x":"date"})
```

Which returns

```sh
   date  player_id  player_rating
0  2006          1             50
1  2010          1             60
2  2006          2             65
3  2008          2             55
4  2012          3             85
```